# Catching and ignoring exceptions from a foreach loop

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

I've tried some of the solutions posted here before, but none seem to be working. In Graph API, the request `var roles = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();` returns both Role IDs and Group IDs. You cannot natively show display names, so you have to request .DirectoryRoles and .Groups while filtering on the returned IDs from .Me.MemberOf. The problem is if you try to lookup a Role ID with a Group ID, it throws an exception because it doesn't exist. I'd like to ignore that, not even display the exception, and move on. My current try/catch is not actually catching the exception though.

```
 var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var roles = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                var id = role.Id;
                var assignments = await graphClient.DirectoryRoles.Request().Filter($"Id eq '{id}'").GetAsync();
                var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"Id eq '{id}'").GetAsync();
                foreach (var assignment in assignments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigned Roles: " + assignment.DisplayName);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Seems like your try block doesn't cover the riskey area of the code... move the deangouros lines into it and see what happens.

Comment: Move all the code that's in the outer foreach into a try-catch block and remove the try-catch in the inner foreach

Answer (score 2):

Your try/catch block doesn't cover the risky lines of code. Look for stack trace in your console output and find exception throwing lines.

Answer (score 1):

use the continue keyword to skip a specific iteration of a foreach loop.

```
var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
var roles = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (var role in roles)
{
    try{

        var id = role.Id;
        var assignments = await graphClient.DirectoryRoles.Request().Filter($"Id eq '{id}'").GetAsync();
        var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"Id eq '{id}'").GetAsync();
        foreach (var assignment in assignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assigned Roles: " + assignment.DisplayName);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

If this still throws errors then move the top 3 lines into the try catch block.